# Confirmation of MGF of Shifted Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, moment-generating-function

Consider the probability distribution $D \sim X - a$ where $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. My task is to find the MGF of probability distribution $D$. I think I have a solution but it contradicts what I thought would be the intuitive solution, so I would like to confirm my work:

For $D \sim X - 5$ where $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, the PDF of $D$ is given by
$$ f_D(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(x+a)} \quad \text{ for } x \geq -a $$
and so
\begin{align*}
M_D(t)
&= \text{E}_D\left[ e^{tx}  \right] \\
&= \int_{-a}^{\infty} e^{tx} \lambda e^{-\lambda(x+a)} \text{d}x \\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda a} \int_{-a}^{\infty} e^{-x(\lambda - t)} \text{d}x \\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda a} \left( \frac{1}{t - \lambda} \right) \left( 0 - e^{a(\lambda - t)} \right)  \\
&= e^{-at} \left( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t} \right)
\end{align*}
This result seems believable, but (before doing any actual math) I had originally suspected $M_D(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - (t+a)}$. Are there flaws with my solution method, or does $M_D(t) = e^{-at} \left( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t} \right)$ seem reasonable? I am having a hard time convincing myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the effect of change of origin and scale on moment generating function? Specifically if $X\mapsto \frac{X-a}{h}=: U, $ then what is $M_U(t) $ and is it related to $M_X(t) $ in any way?

The observation is simple:

$$ M_U(t) =\mathbb E\exp(tU)=\mathbb E\exp\left[\frac{-at}{h}+\frac{tX}{h}\right]=\exp\left[\frac{-at}{h}\right]\mathbb E\exp\left[\frac{tX}{h}\right]=\exp\left[\frac{-at}{h}\right] M_X\left(\frac{t}{h}\right).\tag 1$$

Using this, you can check if $X\sim\textrm{Exp}(\lambda), $ then $M_D(t) =\exp\left[{-at}\right] M_X\left({t}\right)= \exp\left[{-at}\right] \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right).$